# Getting Error400 when signing into Strapi admin panel

Tags: reactjs, localhost, next.js, strapi, http-status-code-400

I have a strapi cms which I use for fetching. Today I ran npm run develop to start the server, and it needed be to login. No big deal, I logged in with my credentials, and it says wrong credentials. I tried the 3 passwords I use, but none of them work. I clicked "forgot password" and waited for the password reset, but it never came. I went back to sign in again, and I notice this message whenever I click the sign in button:

```
POSThttp://localhost:1337/admin/login                       [HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request 95ms]
```

This message is also displayed in my IDE's console:

```
debug POST /admin/login (89 ms) 400
```

I've been trying to login for the past hour but it's still not letting me. I've already restarted the server, the IDE, my computer, as well as clearing cache and cookies, but none of them worked. Any clue to solve this?

Update:
This message is appearing in the console. I wonder if it's relevant? It's weird though because I never modified with the scripts in my IDE.

```
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not parse content for http://localhost:1337/admin/shallowequal.cjs.production.min.js.map: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```